# Space meaning in DFA?

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, automata, dfa

This is a DFA generated by a tool for the regular expression

(a|b)* abaabb (a|b)*

What does space mean in the picture? And do you think it's completely correct because it doesn't show other possibilities for the string abaabb. e.g. what if if b in the middle of the string gets an a?
[image: dfa]

Comment: What is the name of the tool that generated this graph?

Comment: The diagram looks correct to me.  The space in the picture is for the space character ' '.  The alphabet for your expression consists of a, b, and space.

Comment: alphabet is only {a,b}

Comment: oh I didn't know that little space i left in the string is reflected in the diagram.. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[space] refers to the actual space I left in the string (a|b)* abaabb (a|b)*.
That is all.